# Lower Bounds for the increment of the Brownian Motion

Tags: brownian-motion

Let $B_t$ be a Brownian motion in $\left[0,1\right]$. I am pretty sure that is is possible to prove that, for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists an $0<h<\varepsilon$
such that

$$
\left|B_{t+h}-B_t\right|\geq C\,\sqrt{h\,\log\left(1/h\right)}, \text{ a.s.}
$$

for all $t\in[0,1-h]$. There is a proof in the book by [Morters and Peres (2010)](https://books.google.it/books?id=e-TbA-dSrzYC&pg=PR4&lpg=PR4&dq=M%20%CC%88orters%20and%20Peres%20(2010)&source=bl&ots=T0n5MGsLVU&sig=4fJ_pzV4cD4e6LJ1OyF-KbS7Zqc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjMzYe61c3QAhVLCBoKHQ7SCggQ6AEIIjAC#v=onepage&q=M%20%CC%88orters%20and%20Peres%20(2010)&f=false) (Theorem 1.13) which is not pretty clear to me, even the statement says that "there exist $0<h<\varepsilon$ and $t\in[0,1-h]$":

[image]

while I think it should be for all $h\in\left(0,\varepsilon\right)$ and $t\in[0,1-h]$. In fact in the proof they claim to have proved that, for all $\varepsilon>0$

[image]

Which is pretty strange to me, I would expect something as

$$
\forall h\in\left(0,\varepsilon\right),\forall t\in[0,1-h],\mathbb{P}\left\{\left|B_{t+h}-B_t\right|\leq c\,\sqrt{h\,\log(1/h)} \right\}=0
$$

Am I missing something? Any suggestion?